# Finding the rate of a reaction given experimental data for reaction kinetics

Tags: physical-chemistry, kinetics, rate-equation

Here is the question:

> For the reaction:
> $$\ce{2 A + 2 B  →  C + D}$$
>
> The following data was obtained from three experiments:
> \begin{array}{c|ccc}\hline
> \bf{Experiment} &\textbf{[A] (mol/L)} &\textbf{[B] (mol/L)} &\textbf{Rate of Formation of C(mol min/L )} \\ \hline
> 1 & 0.60 &0.15 &6.3 \times10^{-3} \\
> 2 & 0.20 & 0.60 & 2.8 \times 10^{-3}\\
> 3 & 0.20 &0.15& 7.0 \times10^{-4} \\ \hline
> \end{array}
>
> a) What is the rate equation for the reaction?
>
> b) What is the numerical value of the rate constant $k$?
>
> c) Propose a reaction mechanism for this reaction, identify any intermediates, and the rate-determining step.

What I have done:

[image]

However, I don't know if this is correct and how to proceed forward :/

Edit:
I fixed my rate law however When determining the reaction mechanism, I am having a hard time cause I am not sure of the possible mechanism that indicates a slow step, how would I do this part?

Comment: I am unable to understand what your efforts stand for. Could you please clarify?

Comment: The image you posted has a very low resolution so it is hard to see what you wrote there. Could you perhaps post an image with a good resolution, or even better, type it in with MathJax ?

Comment: Your method is correct. Try getting the exponent of $[A]$ again. It should be +2, not -2.

Answer (score 5):

As I said in the comments, your image is quite low resolution. But, if I read it correctly, you have got the exponents in the rate law wrong.

Solving this type of problem is simple, you just need to check if the rate law makes intuitive sense. The data given in the question contains various instantaneous rates (or initial rates maybe) with concentrations at that point.

First, look at the data:
\begin{array}{c|ccc}\hline
\bf{Experiment} &\textbf{[A] (mol/L)} &\textbf{[B] (mol/L)} &\textbf{Rate of Formation of C(mol min/L )} \\ \hline
1 & 0.60 &0.15 &6.3 \times10^{-3} \\
2 & 0.20 & 0.60 & 2.8 \times 10^{-3}\\
3 & 0.20 &0.15& 7.0 \times10^{-4} \\ \hline
\end{array}

From experiment 1 & 3., the rate increases by 9 times when you increase $\text{[A]}$ by 3 times. Clearly, the exponent of $\text{[A]}$ in the rate equation is $2$.

Now from experiments 2 & 3, the rate increases by $4$ times when you increase $\text{[B]}$ by 4 times. The exponent of $\text{[B]}$ in rate eqn. is 1.

So your rate law should be $$r=k\mathrm{[A]^2[B]}$$

I think in your calculation you switched the numerator and denominator somewhere so you got negative exponents.

Then you can use the rate equation with the data given to find the rate constant.

Proposing the reaction mechanism is a bit difficult, remember that most elementary reaction steps are bimolecular. Trimolecular steps are rare. Any step where more than 3 species collide is almost impossible, so make sure your mechanism doesn't have anything like that.

**Edit**: For writing a plausible mechanism, in general keep in mind that the rate law will have terms for all of the reactant species that are present in and before the slow (rate limiting) step.

An example mechanism for the reaction could be something like the following:

$$\ce{A +B-> X_1}$$
$$\ce{X_1 +A \overset{slow}{->} C + X_2}$$
$$\ce{X_2 + B -> D}$$

$\ce{X_1}$ and $\ce{X_2}$ are intermediates.

To get the rate law, count the number of reagent molecules (not the intermediates) for the slow step and all steps before that. So in the slow step you have one molecule of A, in the previous step you have one molecule of A and one of B. So, your rate law should be $\mathrm{r=k[A]^2[B]}$ which is the same as you got from experiment, so this is a possible mehcanism (this is not a proof that the mechanism is right!)

Note that the above way of getting the rate law from mechanism is simplistic, so there might be some unusual reactions where it fails.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! I fixed my rate law the way you have explained it! When determining the reaction mechanism, I am having a hard time cause I am not sure of the possible mechanism that indicates a slow step, how would I do this part?

Comment: @Mia See the edit.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification!